# Find ${\alpha\beta}^{205}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\alpha =$ $(1 4 3 2)(7 6 5)$ and $\beta =$ $(12)(34)$

Find ${\alpha\beta}^{205}$.

Are there any tricks to this question that can help me? I have not worked with such a high power with cycles.

Comment: Is it $\alpha\, \beta^{205}$ or $(\alpha\, \beta)^{205}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

- Note that ***disjoint cycles commute***, and $\beta^{2}= (1 2)(34) (12)(34) = e$

**Added.** So (if my calculations are right) your $\alpha\beta = (24)(765)$.  Now note that $(\alpha\beta)^{6}=e$. Therefore you have $$(\alpha\beta)^{205} = (\alpha\beta)^{204}\cdot \alpha\beta = \alpha\beta$$

Comment: so since they commute, ${\alpha\beta}^{205} = \alpha^{205}\beta^{205}$. Since $\beta^2 = e$, I also noticed that $\beta^3 = \beta$. So is it true that $\beta$ to an even power is the identity and $\beta$ to an odd power is $\beta$?

Comment: Yes. $\beta^{odd}=\beta$. But $\alpha$ and $\beta$ don't commute, because $\alpha$ and $\beta$ aren't disjoint, so you can't use $(\alpha\beta)^{205}=\alpha^{205}\beta^{205}$

Comment: @rover2: Would you mind adding parentheses around αβ?

Comment: @Bernard I am not really sure, where i should be adding the parentheses, but if you feel anything improper feel free to edit. Thanks :)

Comment: @S.C.: I've withdrawn my comment (I hadn't read the details of the question).  Personally, I'd write $\alpha\beta=(34)(576)$.